# Documentar api en java con Swagger

Tags: java, api, spring, swagger, swagger-ui

Hola tengo un pequeño proyecto en el cual quiero documentar la api y no puedo porque swagger no muestra mi documentacion, en otras palabras no puedo acceder a la documentacion.

Codigo:
Interface Repositorio:

```html
@Repository
public interface LibroRepo extends JpaRepository<Libros,Integer> {
}
```

---

Clase Libro:

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "Lib")
public class Libros {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String autor;
    private String titulo;
    private double precio;
```

### Con sus getters y setter(no los agrego aquí porque son innecesarios).

Clase Controlador:

```html
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/nada")
public class Ctrl {

    @Autowired
    private LibroRepo repo;

    @GetMapping("/hola")
    public String getSaludo(){
        return "hola como estas(?";
    }

    @GetMapping("/Book")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Libros>> Person(){
        List<Libros> librosList=(List<Libros>) this.repo.findAll();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(librosList);
    }

    @PostMapping("/Create")
    public ResponseEntity<Libros> Create(@RequestBody Libros libros){
        Libros LibroCreado=this.repo.save(libros);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(LibroCreado);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/Delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Libros> Delete(@PathVariable int id){
        this.repo.deleteById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

---

Clase SwaggerConfig: esta sera la clase en donde mostrara la info de la api.

```html
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
```

---

En cuanto a las dependencias en el pom tengo la dependencia para conectarme a la base de datos(JPA),Spring web, H2 SQL(como base de datos), swagger-ui, swagger2, y sprinfox-boot-starter.

no se cual es el error el cual me impide acceder a la url para ver la documentacion de la api.

Las URL que utilizo para probar:

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui./index.html

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/

y ninguno funciona.

También probé con la etiqueta @EnableSwagger2 y no obtuve buenos resultados.

Comment: ¿Hay algún tipo de error que se vea por la consola? ¿Funciona `http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs/`? Sería importante saber si la versión de Spring Boot que estás usando es mayor que la 2.6. Te sugiero agregar esta línea en tu `application.properties`: spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
tal cual está explicado [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241843/failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsbootstrapper-in-spring-data-rest) Con Spring Boot no es necesario el uso de `@EnableSwagger2`. En el siguiente [artículo](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-fo

Answer (score 0):

Yo personalemte prefiero

SpringDoc https://springdoc.org/#getting-started que utiliza OpenAPI 3, ya que springfox esta al parecer fuera mantenimiento

Te recomiendo ver la url mensionada para entender como configurar etc

Es tan simple como añadir la siguiente dependencia

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.14</version>
   </dependency>
```

Si quieres puede definir la url en el application.properties ( ver paso3.2 del get statted)

```
# /api-docs endpoint custom path
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
```